# Bootstrap 3 Button Groups - how to make them links?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This seems really dumb to me, but what are the point of Bootstrap 3's button groups if you can't make them links?

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups

We've tried this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="add.php">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
</button>
```

And...

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
<a href="add.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add</a>
</button>
```

But neither work as links.  What am I not understanding here?
Thank you.
NJ

Comment: Check [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified) where bootstrap mentions about using `a` in button groups.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the classes in bootstrap to change the `a` tag.

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Left</a>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Middle</a>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Right</a>
</div>

<a href="add.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
</a
```

See the example here - http://www.bootply.com/v8anIQZU97

Answer (score 0):

HTML buttons don't have an href attribute.  Instead try using anchor tags.  Here's a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xjGSNqjTxFxRRHltisXP?p=preview) that illustrates a button group using anchor tags to open search engines in a new window.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
    ....
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")'">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
 </button>
```